# How to deal with whitespaces in scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to find certain files on my external disc and delete those. I created following script (to test I only use ls $i to check the output)

```
for i in `find /media/My\ Book/ -name "OP_CACHE.IDX" -print`; 
  do ls $i; 
done
```

The problem is, that the find-command returns just strings where the whitespaces (e.g. "My Book") are not encoded (like i do in /media/My\ Book) and hence I get errors that the folders cannot be found.

How can I solve this problem with the whitespaces? Is there a flag for find, or something?

regards
Marc

Comment: for i in ``something`` is a known bash pitfall. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* a flag for `find`, and it's used like this:

```
find "/media/My Book" -name "OP_CACHE.IDX" -exec ls {} \;
```

This can be used too:

```
find "/media/My Book" -name "OP_CACHE.IDX" -print0 | xargs -0 ls
```

(The `-print0` argument tells `find` to separate filenames by null bytes, not by newlines. In most modern filesystems (ext3 and NTFS for example), filenames can contain not just spaces but also newlines, tabs, everything except a null byte. While it is very unlikely for your own disk to have such filenames, I tend to be careful about that.)

---

If you are going to just delete the files later, `find` can do that too:

```
find "/media/My Book" -name "OP_CACHE.IDX" -delete
```

(You can even use `-print -delete` to see each file as it's being removed.)

---

If you absolutely must use a bash loop, this will work most of the time:

```
find "/media/My Book" -name "OP_CACHE.IDX" | while read file; do
  ls "$file"
done
```

But see the comment about `-print0` above.

Answer (score 1):

You should pipe your `find` into `while read`:

```
find ... | while read i
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `for ...`, use `while read`, like so:

```
find .... | while read LINE ; do
  ls "$LINE"
done
```

It will read one line at a time and put it in the `LINE` variable. Thus it doesn't matter if find doesn't escape the spaces. I have also wrapped the ls in `"`'s, which prevent a space there from messing it up